# Get html value to pass to php withini the file

Tags: php, html

How can I get an HTML value to send to PHP. I would like to avoid using a form. For example I have an input:

```
<input name="input" id="input">Input</input>
```

while in PHP:

`$input = $_POST['input']` --> but didn't work

or

`$input = $_GET['input']` --> still didn't work

I know that I will be able to get it using form then `action="another file"` but I want it within a file. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Probably the GET method will work, you just need to append the parameter to the url like: /?input=VALUE_HERE

Comment: could you give me an example? i don't get what you mean

Comment: View my answer below

Comment: what trigger to get your `input` value? when user finish input or what? it is exist submit button?

Comment: @Rin_asdfghjkl i updated my answer see if it helps

Comment: why do you want to avoid using form ? HTML forms are standard way of sending data to the server. Maybe your scenario is different could you add more information in your question ?

Comment: @QambarRaza he wants to show entered value on the same page w/o sending data to another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to use `js` to append the `input value` in `url variable` then you can use `js function` as follows;

**client.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <a onclick="append()" id="anch" href="server.php?text">Send value</a>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function append()
    {
        txt=document.getElementById('txt');
        anch=document.getElementById('anch');
        anch.href=anch.href+"="+txt.value;
    }
</script>
```

**server.php**

```
$variable = $_GET["input"];
echo $variable;
```

**Output on localhost:**

[image]

After clicking send value:-

[image]

**Update:** I just read the end of your question. If you want to show the value of input on same page/file then you can use following code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['text']))
        {
            $text=$_GET['text'];
            echo "<a onclick='append()' id='anch' href='?text=$text'>Enter Value</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a onclick='append()' id='anch' href='?text'>Enter Value</a>";
        }
    ?>

    <br>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['text']))
        echo "<div id='values'>".$_GET['text']."<div>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function append()
    {
        txt=document.getElementById('txt');
        anch=document.getElementById('anch');
        if(anch.href.match(/=/)=="=")
        anch.href=anch.href+txt.value+"<br>";
        else
        anch.href=anch.href+"="+txt.value+"<br>";
    }
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Check output on **[phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d6ni-pdm0)**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way to go is to use the GET method.

You will need to access your page with the get parameters included like this:

> http://localhost/index.php?input=VALUE_HERE

And in your php file:

```
$variable = $_GET["input"];
echo $variable;
```

But if you insist to use inline html elements to get data, you need to use javascript for that like this for jquery:

```
alert("This is the value of the input" + $("#input").val());
```

Comment: I believe that u used this http://localhost/index.php?input=VALUE_HERE to pass data to another page. I've done this in updating data, but would like to depend on ONE file only.

Comment: regarding the javascript, i dont know how i can get the value from jquery to php

Comment: Do you want to create a form and submit it without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this
`<input name="input" id="input">Input</input>`
Use this
`<input name="input" id="input">`